# Accidentally deleted Bluetooth from Android

Tags: bluetooth

Yesterday I got a message from perhaps one of my antivirus that "Bluetooth Share has permission to send text messages without your permission and may cost money". It gave me the option to delete it and stupidly I said yes. To be honest, I thought an app called Bluetooth "Share" would not be the actual Bluetooth apk I used on my phone but rather some third-party app from the Play store. But now I cannot use Bluetooth on my phone and I have no idea how to fix it.

My phone isn't rooted and if anyone has any idea how to restore Bluetooth on my Android 7.0 Moto G4 I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

Go to settings -> Applications -> Reset application settings.

Google Play Protect caused the issue and disables the software.

Answer (score 0):

Your AV shouldn't be able to delete system apps (assuming it's not using root). At worst it can disable them and you can restore it from either app management in system settings or you can check if your AV has a restore option.

Comment: There is no Bluetooth app even in the disabled section of apps in settings, and my AV (Kaspersky) doesn't seem to have a restore app function..